# Fail the SQL Server agent job in case any one of the step failed to complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-administration

I have job which has only one step. This step calls an SSIS package. Most of the time it is running fine however sometimes it is failing due to connectivity some issues.

It is very hard to track this kind of failure since when I open the job history (screenshot below) it shows the job is completed successfully. When I click on the step which I highlighted on the same screenshot I could see the error.

I have plenty of jobs like this and it is very hard to track these kind of errors manually.

[image]

The below is the actual error due to which the job step is failed however the overall job status showing it as success.

[image]

This is a weird scenario and impossible to track. We already have job failure reporting mechanism where it tracks only the over all job failure but it unable to track the Job step failures.

Logically speaking the overall status of the job should fail if one or more steps failed to complete. I have checked the Advanced option below looks like everything is fine. I am not sure where to start with. Please provide some insights on this.

[image]

Comment: Is, perhaps, the package or the node set to always report success? The agent relies on the package reporting a failure, and it appears that the package is not, which implies the error is being handled within the package and the error to not be a failure. As a result a failure isn't propagated to the agent.

Comment: Did you see _The package execution returned DTSER__SUCCESS ... The package executed successfully_?

Comment: @Larnu - You are right, The error has been handled at Error Handler. Logging the error to SSISErrorLog Table. Is anyway we can return the error message again to Job Agent.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, @StackUser. Packages and nodes have a `ForceExecutionResult` property; I am suggesting that perhaps the node(s) (that are failing) or the package have that set to `Success`.

Comment: @Larnu - I have confirmed that the ForceExecutionResult Property value is None at the package. What you meant by node here. You mean each task in control flow. If so, all nodes have the same value "None". Not sure how to proceed on this.

Comment: *"You mean each task in control flow."* Yes. If the task that errors is *forced* to return Success, the Agent won't see that as a failure, as it will mean the package doesn't return an failure at the end (if no other failures occur that are ignored).

Comment: @Larnu: I edited my previous comment. Please review.

Comment: The fact remains, @StackUser, the package is returning a "Success", so *something* is telling the package to not treat that error as a failure. We don't have access to your package, so we can't really tell you any more.

Comment: Side note: I really recommend switching to SSISDB, the amount of logs you can get are significantly greater from the agent and you can see in much more detail what the package did.